# Windows: Python SSL certificate verify failed while running a simple telegram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, telegram-bot

I am trying to run a simple telegram bot code via python and i keep getting this error. I am fairly new to python and just cant get to understand even some of the online solutions proposed. I am not sure on how i should get the SSL certificate installed if at all that is the problem.

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hello, how are you doing?")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)

bot.polling()
```

Here is the Traceback for reference:

```
2020-03-26 12:48:57,541 (util.py:66 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "SSLError occurred, args=(SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 238, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 279, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 574, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 60, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 279, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 249, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 194, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 58, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 238, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 279, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\1025632\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)
```

Comment: *"I am fairly new to python and just cant get to understand even some of the online solutions proposed."* - Given that you've found some solution but don't understand it I'm not sure what you expect by just asking it again: you probably again will not understand the answer. It would be more helpful if you instead explain what you've found and what exactly don't understand.

Comment: i mentioned that while i searched a lot on this error nothing worked for me and i still get this error. I confirm i have not fixed my issue yet. Maybe I was not clear

Comment: I am still getting the error mentioned in the traceback. Code fails with error

Comment: *"i searched a lot on this error nothing worked for me"* - which says exactly zero what you've actually tried and if all the tests resulted in exactly the same error or different errors.